# Variables to check return values in a series of syscalls

Tags: c++, coding-style

What is the convention for creating variables to store return values from syscalls? Create a single variable for all of the calls? Or instantiate a new variable each time?

Edit: Assume some error-handling will be performed in place of the assertion below.

```
void my function() {

    int r = syscall1();
    assert(r != -1);

    int r2 = syscall2();
    assert(r != -1);

}
```

Or

```
void my function() {

    int r = -1;

    r = syscall1();
    assert(r != -1);

    r = syscall2();
    assert(r != -1);

}
```

Comment: Obviously the second version is preferred, because the first version is ill-formed, and won't even compile.

Comment: If you don't need the return value from the syscall later on (which should be a long int btw) it's strictly better to use a single variable for each subsequent call.

Comment: I'm assuming in the first example, the second "r" was meant to be named something else. As stated above, the first example won't compile. I'd still prefer the second example just to reduce the number of variables. But performance-wise there is no difference if optimizations are enabled.

Comment: If the variable is going to change, or possibly change, you can use a type of `auto` for the variable type. Then assert to see if the types are the same. If you expect different return values, use more than one.